# Port C# code to JAVA (Web service caller)

Tags: c#, java, web-services, port

So I have this function in C# that I need to port to JAVA

```
    public static Response CallService(string strURL, string Token, int timeout, bool isPostMethod = true)
    {
        string error = "";
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        try
        {
            if (strURL.Contains("https"))
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };


            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);


            if (isPostMethod)
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            else
                httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";


            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = timeout;
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Token"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Token, Encoding.UTF8);


            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;

            return new Response(statusCode, httpResponse.GetResponseStream());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) && error.Contains("401"))
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }

        return new Response(statusCode, null, error);
    }
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static Response CallService(String strURL, String Token, int timeout, Boolean isPostMethod) {

    String error = "";
    int statusCode = HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);

        // Allow non trusted ssl certificates
        if(strURL.startsWith("https"))
        {               
            TrustManagerManipulator.allowAllSSL();
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (isPostMethod) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }
        else {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        // Allow Inputs                                                     
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);                                              

        // Allow Outputs                                                    
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                                             

        // Don't use a cached copy.                                         
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);       

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");                

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");        

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Token", Token);

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);   

        statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        return new Response(statusCode, urlConnection.getInputStream(), "");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        error = ex.getMessage();

        if (error != null && !error.equals("") && error.contains("401"))
            statusCode = HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;
    } finally {

    }

    return new Response(statusCode, null, error);

}
```

I'd like to know if I have ported the function successfully because I"m getting an error every time (urlConnection.getInputStream()) is executed

Here's the Response class in C#:

```
public class Response
{
    private HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    private Stream responseStream;
    private string exception;

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get { return statusCode; } }
    public Stream ResponseStream { get { return responseStream; } }
    public string ExceptionError { get { return exception; } }

    public Response(HttpStatusCode code, Stream stream, string strException = "")
    {
        this.statusCode = code;
        this.responseStream = stream;
        this.exception = strException;
    }
}
```

And Here's the Ported Response Class in Java:

```
public static class Response
{
    private int statusCode;
    private InputStream responseStream;
    private String exception;

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public InputStream getResponseStream() {
        return responseStream;
    }

    public String getExceptionError() {
        return exception;
    }

    public Response(int code, InputStream stream, String strException)
    {
        this.statusCode = code;
        this.responseStream = stream;
        this.exception = strException;
    }
}
```

Comment: _I'd like to know if I have ported the function successfully because I"m getting an error every time (urlConnection.getInputStream()) is executed_ Which error?

Comment: @BackSlash Here's the exception: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: http://...